# How can I make a text/string container in the inspector for adding descriptions/info text and how to fit and convert it to ui text component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableItem[] lookObj = null;
    public Text text;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public float maxDistance = 10f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = true;

    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private Quaternion savedRotation;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                //if (lookAt.magnitude > maxDistance) continue;
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show found object by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                text.text = primaryTarget.description;
            }
            else
            {
                text.text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class InteractableItem that is attached to each interactable item object :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float distance = 10f;
    public string description = "";
}
```

Now I'm using a simple string and then show it in the IKControl script :

```
                if (primaryTarget != null)
                {
                    text.text = primaryTarget.description;
                }
                else
                {
                    text.text = "";
                }
```

but there are two problems :

- Typing description in a string in the inspector is a bad idea because soon very soon the text is getting out the string field.
- The text in the game view window on the left bottom is too much to the left and depending on how much I feed a description text it will get out the screen. I need to change the ui text width all the time but that is not a solution.

[image: The text in the inspector and in the game view]

Cube is interactable item :

Maybe instead just a string to use a ui text also on each item ? or maybe another text container ? and then how to use it in the IKControl script ?

Comment: Have you tried custom inspectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're asking correctly, for most descriptions you can just make a public string that has `[TextArea]` attribute. You can find a [complete list of attributes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAreaAttribute.html) pretty easily, there are lots of them and you can start doing some really cool things in the inspector if you utilize them correctly.